# You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element in Knockout.Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'v applied binding only once, but still getting error

> You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

This is my script.

```
    <script>
var self = this;
         var vm = function viewModel() {
                self.getAppointment = function () {
                    $("#dialog-confirm ").dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        height: 250,
                        width: 500,
                        modal: true
                    });

                    self.checkAppointmentListSelect(true);
                }

                self.checkAppointmentListSelect = ko.observable(false);

                self.btnSelectAppointmentClick = function () {
                    self.checkAppointmentListSelect(true);
                }
                debugger;
            }

            ko.applyBindings(vm);
    </script>
```

This is the html data

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Select Appointment">
        <div class="modal-body" data-bind="visible: checkAppointmentListSelect">

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSelectAppointment" data-bind="click: btnSelectAppointmentClick">Select</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" data-bind="visible: checkAppointmentListSelect">

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSelectAppointment">Select </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This code is working fine, can you add code samples of your view? Do you have more places where you call ko.applyBindings?

Comment: Is the the _only_ place that knockout is being used on that page, or are you using it twice for two different areas?

Comment: nope, only in this page

Comment: There's something else going on somewhere that's not in your question.  I note it's a dialog - is this perhaps being loaded dynamically, with it perhaps failing on the second and subsequent attempts?  Otherwise there's not a lot we can go on from what you've posted.

Comment: Also a few points: `var self = this;` in your code is outside of the VM, it is hard to tell from your post, but it is probably the `window` object. You are not supposed to assign your VM props to that. Create a separate object instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

- `var self = this;` should be inside the constructor function. Outside, `this` refers to the window object.
- You should pass an **object** containing `observable` properties to `ko.applyBindings()`. Not the function itself.
- You either use [Function Expression or Function Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) to create a function in javascript. `viewModel` in your code is not required. It's either 
  `var vm = function() {}` or `function vm(){}`.
- You have set `checkAppointmentListSelect` to `false` by default. Your buttons won't be displayed on load for you to click.

Change your code to:

```
function vm() {
  var self = this; // this should be inside the vm function

  self.getAppointment = function() {
    $("#dialog-confirm ").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 250,
      width: 500,
      modal: true
    });

    self.checkAppointmentListSelect(true);
  }

  self.checkAppointmentListSelect = ko.observable(true);

  self.btnSelectAppointmentClick = function() {
    self.checkAppointmentListSelect(true);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm()); // `new vm()` creates an object of type vm
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/ntp6nhL8/). Make all these changes and let me know if you're still facing any issue.